# echo multi-line json file in Dockerfile with environment variable values

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I am trying to dynamically generate a json file during my build step of my container via Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

// ... snipped

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo $'{\n\
  "type": "some_type",\n\
  "project_id": "$PROJECT_ID",\n\
  "private_key_id": "$PRIVATE_KEY_ID"\n\
}' > /etc/my_creds.json

EXPOSE 80
```

This works fine, so when I shell into my container and `cat /etc/my-creds.json` file, it appears the environment variables `$PROJECT_ID` and `$PRIVATE_KEY_ID` were written literally, they did not get replaced with the environment variable values that were present.

I.e. the file looks like this in the container:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The variables will be expanded by the shell if you use double-quotes and escaping, for example:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV FOO=bar
RUN echo "{\"foo\": \"$FOO\"}" >foo.json
```

```
$ docker build -t foo .
$ docker run foo cat foo.json
{"foo": "bar"}
```